# Large sample distribution arising from a beta distribution

Tags: self-study, normality-assumption, beta-distribution

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables having p.d.f as,

$f(x)=\frac{1}{B(6,4)}x^5(1-x)^3,0<x<1.$

Let $Y_i=\frac{X_i}{1-X_i}$ and $U_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum Y_i.$We have to find,if the distribution of $\sqrt n\frac{(U_n-2)}{\alpha}$ converges to $N(0,1)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$,what should be the possible value of $\alpha.$

I tried in this way,

$X\backsim B(6,4)$$\rightarrow Y_i=\frac{X_i}{1-X_i}\backsim B(6,4)$ of 2nd kind.

Now we have to find $E(U_n)$ and $V(U_n)$,as,$\frac{(U_n-E(U_n))}{\sqrt {V(U_n)}}\rightarrow N(0,1)$ when $n\rightarrow{\infty}$

From the question,it seems that $E(U_n)$ should be $2$.But integrating $f(x),$ I am getting $E(X_n)=E(U_n)=\frac{1}{840}$ which is quite impossible in this case.

How can we get the required result?

Comment: What exactly did you integrate?

Comment: Thank you.I was making a mistake while integrating.$\frac{1}{B(6,4)}\int_0^{\infty}x\frac{x^{6-1}}{{(1+x)}^{10}}$ which is equal to 2 :) I should have rechecked it before asking.